# How to return the actual type rather than an Object type from a method that can work for multiple Class types?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting, jdo

Is there any way to modify the `findModel` method in `SubService` ***to return a `Foo` or `Boo` 
type rather than an `Object` type***.

**I'd like to be able to just call `findModel` from `FooService` or `BooService` without casting to a `Foo` or `Boo` model object.**

Is that possible?

### SubService:

```
public Object findModel(long id, Class modelClass) {

    Object modelObject = null;
    javax.jdo.Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery(modelClass);
    query.setFilter("id == idParam");
    query.declareParameters("long idParam");
    List<Object> modelObjects = (List<Object>) query.execute(id);
    if(modelObjects.isEmpty()){
        modelObject = null;
    }
    else{
        modelObject = modelObjects.get(0);
    }
    return modelObject;

}
```

### FooService extends SubService:

```
public Foo getFoo(long id) {

    Foo modelObject = (Foo)this.findModel(id, Foo.class);
    return modelObject;

}
```

### BooService extends SubService:

```
public Boo getBoo(long id) {

    Boo modelObject = (Boo)this.findModel(id, Boo.class);
    return modelObject;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Redefine method with generics:

```
public <T> T findModel(long id, Class<T> modelClass)
```

Now it will return what you need and you do not need casting.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your objects in you findModel to `SubService`

```
public SubService findModel(long id, Class modelClass)  {
     return (SubService) modelObject;
}
```

Then you can drop the casting in fooService

```
Foo modelObject = this.findModel(id, Foo.class);
```